# Codeigniter Insert multiple rows in db with a table form

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I've found similar questions but, I'm failing to find any answers that works for my situation.

Using Codeigniter:
I have a db table for products and a db table for inventory.  I want to display an html table on my site, each row being a product.  I've included an image to help explain.

[image: Table of Products]

Upon submission, I would like to insert each product row of data as an individual row in the database.

This is my controller at its most simplest form...

CONTROLLER----------------------------------

```
function add_show_inventory() 
    {
        $data['products']=$this->product->get_products();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('skuID', 'skuID', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('brought-in', '"Brought In"', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('finished-with', '"Finished With"', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('deliveries', 'Deliveries');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('add-1', 'Add 1');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('add-2', 'Add 2');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('band-comp', 'Band Comp');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('other-comp', 'Other Comp');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('half-sales', 'Half Sales');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('half-amount', 'Half Amount');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error-module">', '</div>');

        if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE){
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('menu');
            $this->load->view('inventory/show-add-inventory', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');
        } else {
            if($_POST){

                $data=array(
                    'brought-in'=>$_POST['brought-in'],
                );

                $this->inventory->insert_inventory($data);
                redirect(base_url().'shows/');
            }
        }
    }
```

GET PRODUCTS MODEL -------------------------------

```
function get_products($num=10,$start=0) {
        $where= array('userID'=>$this->session->userdata('userID'), 'active'=>1);

        $this->db->select()
                         ->from('products')
                         ->where($where)
                         ->order_by('product','asc')
                         ->limit($num,$start);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

INSERT INV MODEL------------------------------------------

```
function insert_inventory($data) {
    $product_count= $this->db->count_all('products');

    for ($i=0; $i < $product_count; $i++) { 
        $this->db->insert('inventory', array('brought-in'=>$_POST['brought-in']));
    }
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

VIEW ------------------------------------------

```
<form action="<?= base_url(); ?>inventories/add_show_inventory" method="post">

<?php if(!isset($products)){ ?>
    <p>There are currently no products posted yet.</p>
<?php } else {
    foreach($products as $row){
?>

    <td class="highlight">
        <input type="text" name="brought-in" value="0"> <!-- Brought In -->
    </td>

<?php } ?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit">
```

The results I get from this code here is Three entrees to the DB which is what I want but all of the rows are identical to the last row in the form... meaning the iteration in the model is only iterating over that last row on the form...

Again that code is stripped down to its simplest form possible so I don't have 3 full pages of code... but if you would like to see anything I am not showing please let me know...

Any and all help much appreciated... I've been working on this for a couple weeks...

Comment: what is coming in $_POST['brought-in']. Single value or an array?

Comment: how are you getting and passing the row from model to view?

Comment: I thought it would be an array of all the brought-in input fields, but I'm pretty sure It's not grabbing an array... and I'm not sure how to make it...

Comment: You mean the product rows?

Comment: Yes product rows. please post your html form , controller method with which you are getting rows to display.

Comment: @raheelshan I've updated the code for more clarity.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your view**:

```
<?php $i=0; foreach($products as $row){ ?>

    <td class="highlight">
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo 'brought-in'.$i; ?>" value="0"> <!-- Brought In -->
    </td>

<?php $i++;} ?>
```

**Now in your controller**:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $count = $this->inventory->fetch_prods_count(); //Write this function in ur model.
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
     $data[$i]=array('brought-in'=>$_POST['brought-in'.$i]);
    }

    $this->inventory->insert_inventory($data,$count);
    redirect(base_url().'shows/');
}
```

**In Model**:

```
function insert_inventory($data,$count) {
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
       $this->db->insert('inventory', $data[$i]);
    }
    return $this->db->insert_id(); //Or just return 1; As U are not processing this value in your controller.
}
```

---

**Update:**
*In your controller*: `inventories/add_show_inventory` function, change

```
$data = array($i=>array('brought-in'=>$_POST['brought-in'.$i]));
```

to

```
$data[$i]=array('brought-in'=>$_POST['brought-in'.$i]);
```

Comment: You can also directly process the POST values in your model without bringing in `$data`. Dat'll save your time... By running the for loop just once.

Comment: This code in particular gives me an error on submit...
 
Undefined index: brought-in..  How is that undefined?

Comment: I forgot to increment $i in view. Actually its like `name = brought-in0` for 1st row, `name = brought-in1` for 2nd row, and so on...

Comment: that seemed to fix the undefined index issue. Thank you. But, now the issue is it reacts as if it successfully wrote to the db by redirecting but nothing actually gets written.  Any ideas?

Comment: @TylerCraft: Enable logging in CI and inside your model just after `$this->db->insert('inventory', $data[$i]);` add this line: `log_message('Info',$this->db->last_query();)` and check whether the query is rite.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm looking for... The last few I see are: model class initialized, file loaded(header,footer .etc) final output sent to browser, and total time. But I don't see anything about writing to a db If I should

Comment: @TylerCraft: That means either `insert_inventory($data,$count)` function is not getting executed or the for loop inside that function is not getting executed probably because `$count = 0;`... Pls check the value of $count.

Comment: I think it's an issue with the fetch prods function.  When I echo $this->db->count_all('products'); I get three.  But when I echo the fetch prods function nothing shows up.  Which mean its not getting called?

Comment: Ya probably its not returning the value...! You are doing this only right `fetch_prods_count() { return $this->db->count_all('products'); }`???

Comment: Ok.. I'm an idiot typo... Now it's return a value of 3 which is how many products I have! Now when I submit I get a couple new errors... #1: undefined offset: 0, and #2: a CI database error, You must use the "set" method to update an entry.  But I'm calling insert not update!

Comment: I do but my Internet is down! Thank you Comcast! But you can email me tyler@blueacorn.com I'm working off a localhost and my phone.

Comment: @TylerCraft: It was because of a silly mistake dat I did. I am very sry abt dat. I've updated my answer.